# Error with Tensorflow 2 in a custom-written layer which worked okay in Tensorflow 1 (assert t.graph == cond_graph; AssertionError)

Tags: tensorflow, graph, keras-layer, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have written a custom-written layer (implementing [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.00158) in Keras). This layer works fine in TF versions (1.13 and 1.15) as I have tested myself. Also, in TF 2.0, when I run `tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()` line after importing Tensorflow module, I encounter no error. However, if I comment the line `tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()` to keep TF2 behavior enabled, an **Assertion Error** will raise.
This is the custom-written layer:

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math


class Conv1D_Sinc(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    @staticmethod
    def to_mel(hz):
        return 2595 * np.log10(1 + hz / 700)

    @staticmethod
    def to_hz(mel):
        return 700 * (10 ** (mel / 2595) - 1)

    def __init__(self,
                 filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 strides=1,
                 padding='same',
                 data_format='channels_last',
                 sample_rate=16000,
                 min_low_hz=50,
                 min_high_hz=50,
                 low_hz=30,
                 **kwargs):

        super(Conv1D_Sinc, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.strides = strides
        self.padding = padding
        self.data_format = data_format
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate
        self.min_low_hz = min_low_hz
        self.min_high_hz = min_high_hz
        self.low_hz = low_hz

        self.weights_init_for_build = True
        self.high_hz = self.sample_rate / 2 - (self.min_low_hz + self.min_high_hz)

        if self.padding == 'causal':
            if self.data_format != 'channels_last':
                raise ValueError('When using causal padding in `Conv1D`, '
                                 '`data_format` must be "channels_last" '
                                 '(temporal data).')
        try:
            kernel_size_number = self.kernel_size[0]
            if kernel_size_number % 2 == 0:
                raise ValueError('''Speed Issue:
                Length of filters ought to be odd (i.e, symmetric).''')
        except:
            if self.kernel_size % 2 == 0:
                raise ValueError('''Speed Issue:
                Length of filters ought to be odd (i.e, symmetric).''')


        if self.data_format == 'channels_first':
            self.channel_axis = 1
        else:
            self.channel_axis = -1


        # mel : (81,) np array
        mel = np.linspace(self.to_mel(self.low_hz), self.to_mel(self.high_hz),
                          self.filters + 1)
        # hz : (81,) np array
        hz = self.to_hz(mel)
        # Hamming window
        n_lin = np.linspace(0, self.kernel_size / 2 - 1, num=int(self.kernel_size / 2))  # computing
        # only half of the window
        self.window_ = np.array((0.54 - 0.46 * np.cos(2 * math.pi * n_lin / self.kernel_size)))
        # (kernel_size, 1)
        n = (self.kernel_size - 1) / 2.0
        self.n_ = np.array(2 * math.pi *
                           np.reshape(np.arange(-n, 0), (1, -1)) /
                           self.sample_rate)  # Due to symmetry, I only need half of the time axes

        # filter lower frequency band (filters, 1) - TRAINABLE VECTORS
        # hz[:,-1] : (80,)
        self.low_vec = np.array(np.reshape(hz[:-1], (-1, 1)))  # low_hz_ (80, 1)

        # filter frequency band (filters, 1) - TRAINABLE VECTORS
        # diff(hz) : (80,)
        self.high_vec = np.array(np.reshape(np.diff(hz), (-1, 1)))  # band_hz_ (80, 1)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        if input_shape[self.channel_axis] is None:
            raise ValueError('The channel dimension of the inputs '+\
                             'should be defined. Found `None`.')
        input_dim = input_shape[self.channel_axis]

        # kernel_size = 251
        # kernel_shape = (251,) + (1, 80)
        # kernel_shape = (251, 1, 80)
        self.kernel_shape = (self.kernel_size,) + (input_dim, self.filters)

        self.kernel_low = self.add_weight(shape=(self.filters, 1),
                                      initializer='zeros', # should be zero.
                                          # I will change it manually in call().
                                      name='kernel_low',
                                      regularizer=None,
                                      constraint=None)

        self.kernel_high = self.add_weight(shape=(self.filters, 1),
                                      initializer='zeros', # should be zero.
                                           # I will change it manually in call().
                                      name='kernel_high',
                                      regularizer=None,
                                      constraint=None)


    def call(self, inputs):
        # input of the call function is : (None, 3200, 1) === (?, 3200, 1)

        if self.weights_init_for_build:
            self.weights_init_for_build = False
            self.kernel_low = self.kernel_low + self.low_vec
            self.kernel_high = self.kernel_high + self.high_vec


        # low = self.min_low_hz + tf.math.abs(self.kernel_low)
        low = self.min_low_hz + K.abs(self.kernel_low)
        high = tf.clip_by_value(low + self.min_high_hz +
                                K.abs(self.kernel_high),
                                self.min_low_hz, self.sample_rate / 2)
        band = (high - low)[:, 0]

        f_times_t_low = K.dot(low, K.variable(self.n_))
        f_times_t_high = K.dot(high, K.variable(self.n_))

        band_pass_left = ((K.sin(f_times_t_high) - K.sin(f_times_t_low)) / (
        self.n_ / 2)) * self.window_  # Equivalent of Eq.4 of the reference paper
        # (SPEAKER RECOGNITION FROM RAW WAVEFORM WITH SINCNET). I just have expanded
        # the sinc and simplified the terms. This way I avoid several useless computations.

        band_pass_center = 2 * K.reshape(band, (-1, 1))
        # band_pass_right = tf.reverse(band_pass_left, axis=[1])
        band_pass_right = K.reverse(band_pass_left, axes=1)
        band_pass = K.concatenate([band_pass_left, band_pass_center, band_pass_right], axis=1)
        band_pass = band_pass / (2 * band[:, None])

        self.kernel_all = K.reshape(band_pass, self.kernel_shape)


        # if self.rank == 1:
        outputs = K.conv1d(
            inputs,
            self.kernel_all,
            strides=self.strides,
            padding=self.padding,
            data_format=self.data_format)
        return outputs



    def get_config(self):
        config = super(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D, self).get_config()
        if 'rank' in config.keys():
            config.pop('rank')
        return config
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/deep/6BED7674319D2F8E/m-a-dastgheib/projects-code/keras/lightNet_v2/main_script_train.py", line 56, in <module>
    history_of_batch = ml_model.train_on_batch(np.expand_dims(input_batch, -1), label_of_batch)
  File "/home/deep/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 973, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight, reset_metrics=reset_metrics)
  File "/home/deep/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py", line 264, in train_on_batch
    output_loss_metrics=model._output_loss_metrics)
  File "/home/deep/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py", line 311, in train_on_batch
    output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics))
  File "/home/deep/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py", line 268, in _process_single_batch
    grads = tape.gradient(scaled_total_loss, trainable_weights)
  File "/home/deep/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/backprop.py", line 1014, in gradient
    unconnected_gradients=unconnected_gradients)
  File "/home/deep/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/imperative_grad.py", line 76, in imperative_grad
    compat.as_str(unconnected_gradients.value))
  File "/home/deep/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/backprop.py", line 138, in _gradient_function
    return grad_fn(mock_op, *out_grads)
  File "/home/deep/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/cond_v2.py", line 166, in _IfGrad
    true_grad_inputs = _resolve_grad_inputs(true_graph, true_grad_graph)
  File "/home/deep/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/cond_v2.py", line 424, in _resolve_grad_inputs
    assert t.graph == cond_graph
AssertionError
```

Thank you in advance for your help.